# What is the term for the sung voice found especially in Bach's chorale music (eg. Jesu Joy of Man's Desire BWV147)?

Tags: voice, terminology

I have wondered what the correct musical term for the voiced melody overlaid in a piece like Jesu Joy of Man's Desire BWV147, or Sleepers Awake BWV645 is. In this piece of music (and other likes it, especially in Bach's music), it's the sung voice, sitting atop the instrumental lines. I thought I'd heard from a teacher that it was called the 'overlay', but I'm not sure this is the right term.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the voiced melody" in BWV 147.10? This is a four-part chorale with instrumental accompaniment. Are you talking about the soprano part?

Comment: Do you mean the *addition* of a choral melody to an instrumental part that was already heard without voices? The German term for that is "Choreinbau" (or more correctly "Vokaleinbau", since the same method appears in many solo arias as well), popularized by Alfred Dürr. I'm not aware of a canonical English translation.

Comment: @replete : perhaps BWV 147 was not a great example, although I do mean the chorale over the instrumental accompaniment in this piece. Another example: BWV 22 "Ertoedt uns durch dine' Guete", in the Harriet Cohen piano transcription, it's the accented tune of the sung part that starts in bar 4 with B flat, -, B flat, C, D, C, -, B flat, D etc. which I think is the sung part in the original cantata.

Comment: @Kilian Foth - yes it may be the Choreinbau, but I thought it might have had a more common English term as it's so common in Bach's work (at least). In Jesu bleibet meine Freude (BWV 147), it famously starts at bar 9 as the 'slower' sung componen.

Comment: To me, a part of Bach's mastery is combining the two, often disparate harmonies together in an integrated whole, and as you can probably tell, I love this aspect of his work. It's difficult to play in a piano transcription though eg. BWV 22, the Harriet Cohen transcription requires a variation in volume for one finger while playing with more than one finger, this very difficult and somewhat counter-intuitive technique starts at the end of bar 4 and takes a break back to the primary melody at bar 7, returning again at the end of bar 8.

Comment: the main voice, either vocal or instrumental can be called *cantus firmus*. It holds the main melody. It is not important to have it as the highest element, so a cantus firmus can be arranged in the bass voice, where the upper voices accompany it. This thechnique is typical for Bach and the whole figured bass era. The other voices are referred to as *counterpoint* often in ths style.

Comment: Thanks @HiDuEi, 'cantus firmus' is the term I think I was looking for. 'Counterpoint' as I understand it relates more to the similar, but contrasting melody lines almost like a 'question - respond - question' format. The 'cantus firmus' in Bach's work then almost overlays a completely different melody, but the genius is making everything work together so naturally!

Comment: @HiDuEi cantus firmus was also typical for renaissance and medieval polyphony, and originally belongs in the tenor voice (which was so named because it "held" the main tune).  By the baroque, it had become common for the melody to be in the soprano voice, so the cantus firmus is often found there as well.  It can of course also appear in the alto, though this will be rarer, and having it in the bass would be quite rare indeed.  I can think of one example off the top of my head, which appears in Brahms, so long after the end of the baroque period.

Answer (score 4):

After researching HiDuEi's comment:

> The main voice, either vocal or instrumental can be called cantus firmus. It holds the main melody. It is not important to have it as the highest element, so a cantus firmus can be arranged in the bass voice, where the upper voices accompany it. This thechnique is typical for Bach and the whole figured bass era. The other voices are referred to as counterpoint often in this style.

and suggestion the term I was looking for is **cantus firmus**, I believe this is the correct answer.

*(HiDuEi, I've posted your comment as the answer, thanks and I hope this helps others!)*

Comment: Yep.  I'd just add that the use of cantus firmus also goes back much further than Bach, to medieval and renaissance music.