# Jesu Joy of Man's Desiring: What term is appropriate for the instrumental ornaments in Bachs Choral arrangements?

Tags: theory, terminology, history

a related question asks if there is a specific term for the voicing in Bach's Chorals:

[What is the term for the sung voice found especially in Bach's chorale music (eg. Jesu Joy of Man's Desire BWV147)?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/81373/what-is-the-term-for-the-sung-voice-found-especially-in-bachs-chorale-music-eg)

I would have said this is the Choral.

But  what I am wondering is how we name the instrumental accompaniment of the solo violin in Jesu Joy or the Bassoon Solo in BWV 140 Zion hört die Wächter singen?

I think we could call it: Ornament, Garland or Ritornell.

Other ideas?

(As I'm planning an analysis and introduction "how to learn and teach"
 this arrangement/setting for piano).

Comment: Just to nitpick... the instrumental accompaniment isn't limited to solo violin, it's full four-part strings. 1st violin is the triplets that everyone knows; 2nd violin is in a dotted swing rhythm; violas and basso continuo are mostly in quarters, as seen in this manuscript: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3DMuLRsr9A. Note when the chorus comes in, their parts are written in between the violas and the continuo (as was typical). Also note the poly-meter: 1st violin part is notated in 9/8, others are in 3/4.

Comment: @Caleb:Yes, it is, of course.But  I'm wondering how you would name these sections and how you'd call the kind of ornaments of the Violin tune.

Answer (score 4):

In the cantata form as used by JS Bach, these "chorale fantasias" often have an elaborate orchestral introduction. The opening of BWV 244 (the St Matthew Passion) has [often been described as such](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1093/jrma/24.1.1?journalCode=rrma18), and both the opening movement and the final movement of BWV 147 *Herz und Mund und Tat und Leben* fit this pattern.

However, the structure of the chorale fantasia conforms fairly well to a sort of [ritornello form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritornello), and hence as the opening theme of the movement does return and punctuate the chorale setting itself, to call this theme a [ritornello](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zV-8tnO2ca8C) is appropriate.